# How to move/save file to VSTS using PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-devops, powershell-2.0, azure-automation

I have a Runbooks in Azure Automation which is a PowerShell script that outputs information to an Excel file. Would it be possible to send that Excel file to VSTS? Does VSTS have a feature to allow file upload to a branch using a PAT?

Comment: Do you have repository in VSTS and you want to upload a file to there?

Comment: Yes, our team has their own repo and want to upload it there so we all have access to it.

Comment: Your repo in VSTS is Git or TFVC?

Comment: Our repo in in Git

Comment: And do you want to upload a file to git repo in vsts with PowerShell?

Comment: Yes because I'm using Azure Automation. I figured out that you can make API requests to that wiki. Now I can't figure out how to make a Put request within PowerShell. I'm using `Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method 'Put' -Body $data -ContentType 'application/json' -headers @{"accept"="application/json"; "authorization"="Basic$($patBase)"; "Content-Type"="application/json"}`

Comment: Can you edit your question with all your code in PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

You just need to achieve below steps by PowerShell:

#### 1. Encode the Excel file with Base64 string

First, you need to get the encode Excel file's base64 string.

#### 2. Get the latest commit on the branch you want to upload excel file

You can use [Get commits REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/commits/get%20commits?view=vsts-rest-4.1) to get the latest commit from the branch:

```
GET https://{account}.visualstudio.com/{ProjectName}/_apis/git/repositories/{repoName}/commits?searchCriteria.itemVersion.version={branchName}&searchCriteria.$top=1&api-version=4.1
```

#### 3. Upload the Excel file to VSTS Git repo via REST API

Then you can add/update the Excel file (with the encode base64 string in step1) to the branch by [Pushes REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/pushes/create?view=vsts-rest-4.1).

- If the Excel has not existed in the branch, you can **add** the excel file to the branch:

  ```
  POST https://{account}.visualstudio.com/{ProjectName}/_apis/git/repositories/{repoName}/pushes?api-version=4.1
  ```

  Body (application/json):

  ```
  {
    "refUpdates": [
      {
        "name": "refs/heads/branchName",
        "oldObjectId": "latest commit sha value get from step2"
      }
    ],
    "commits": [
      {
        "comment": "Added new excel file.",
        "changes": [
          {
            "changeType": "add",
            "item": {
              "path": "/path/to/my.xlsx"
            },
            "newContent": {
              "content": "encode base64 string",
              "contentType": "base64encoded"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  ```
- If the Excel has alredy existed in the branch, you can **update** the excel file to the branch (only change `changeType` as `edit`):

  ```
  POST https://{account}.visualstudio.com/{ProjectName}/_apis/git/repositories/{repoName}/pushes?api-version=4.1
  ```

  Body (application/json):

  ```
  {
    "refUpdates": [
      {
        "name": "refs/heads/branchName",
        "oldObjectId": "latest commit sha value get from step2"
      }
    ],
    "commits": [
      {
        "comment": "Update new excel file.",
        "changes": [
          {
            "changeType": "edit",
            "item": {
              "path": "/path/to/my.xlsx"
            },
            "newContent": {
              "content": "encode base64 string",
              "contentType": "base64encoded"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  ```

And below is the example PowerShell script to upload an excel file to my VSTS git repo (repo3 in G1 project):

```
$url="https://marinaliu.visualstudio.com/G1/_apis/git/repositories/repo3/pushes?api-version=4.1"
$body=
'
{
  "refUpdates": [
    {
      "name": "refs/heads/master",
      "oldObjectId": "27d76947fe5bea4e677cd220fe45530028e634fc"
    }
  ],
  "commits": [
    {
      "comment": "Added new image file.",
      "changes": [
        {
          "changeType": "edit",
          "item": {
            "path": "/images/hello/mar.xlsx"
          },
          "newContent": {
            "content": "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",
            "contentType": "base64encoded"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
'
$user = "username"
$token = "mypatehdq6tilwfjdbgbkymo3f3ojszmrlfgzh3o2fww6kg1nvvq"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
$result=Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body
```